# How to check if price of a product is between given range using assert in selenium java

Tags: java, selenium

I have a test case where I need to go to Jewelry section and select the price range filter of $700.00 - $3000.00. After selecting the range I can see 1 product priced at $2100.00. Now, My question is how do I check using assert that the product price $2100 is between $700 - $3000? Do I need to get rid the $ signed? as actual result will contain $ signed while comparing with expected.

Please help?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this a serious question? assertTrue("Price is too low", 2100 > 700); assertTrue("Price is too high", 2100 < 3000); as for the rest, why would you even have an $ in any of those values?

Comment: Java does not have a money data type.

Answer (score 3):

It is very simple in Java

`assertThat(mynum).isBetween(min, max);`

**Or**

`assertTrue(min <= mynum && mynum <= max);`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to get rid of the $ sign, that's useless and as said in the comments, Java (and probably no other programming language) has a specific money type.

You can use Regex for that

```
"[0-9]+"
```

And for the assert, it's as simple as adding two conditions inside

```
assertTrue(price > 700 && price < 3000);
```